# Search and get with XMLreader and PHP

Tags: php, xmlreader

I have an xml feed, and what to search that with XMLreader for a value like EAN, when i find that value i want to get all XML with in the element that the EAN value is placed within. Can i do that?

```
<prods>
  <prod>
    <ean>price</ean>
    <ean>1234</ean>
  </prod>
  <prod>
    <ean>price</ean>
    <ean>123</ean>
  </prod> 
</prods>
```

So if i search for the value in ean 1234, i want to get the hole prod element. 1 level up sort of saying.

```
<prod>
    <ean>price</ean>
    <ean>1234</ean>
</prod>
```

Comment: You would probably need to find each `<prod>` element and then check the data yourself.  You can get the contents of an element as SimpleXML to make it easier to test.

Comment: Year thats what i was doing allready, but searching the hole file that way was just time consuming, so was thinking the other way could be better.

Comment: Is the file to large to read in 1 go?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xpath to select a `prod` node with your condition :

```
$content = '<prods>
  <prod>
    <ean>price</ean>
    <ean>1234</ean>
  </prod>
  <prod>
    <ean>price</ean>
    <ean>123</ean>
  </prod> 
</prods>' ;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);
$nodes = $xml->xpath("//prod[ean = '1234']") ; // get all prod nodes that satisty "an ean child has content '1234' " 
echo $nodes[0]->asXml();
```

Output :

```
<prod>
    <ean>price</ean>
    <ean>1234</ean>
</prod>
```